# subgroups of regular polytopes that preserve a given face

Tags: convex-analysis, polytopes, convex-geometry, dual-cone

Say I have a regular polytope (e.g. it is vertex and face transitive). Given a face F, is it true that there are symmetry operations taking every vertex of F to every other that also send F to its self? I know that every face of a regular polytope is a regular polytope, so this seems like a logical assertion.

To give an example of where this holds, for a face of a cube there is a cyclic subgroup that permutes all vertices of any of given square face, whilst mapping that face to its self (e.g. the rotations about the normal of that face)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The more general definition of a regular polytope is that its symmetry group acts transitively on its *flags*. A flag is a maximal chain of incident faces, e.g. for a polyhedron, a vertex $v$, an edge $e$ containing $v$, and a face containing $e$.

So, with a regular polyhedron, you can pick a vertex $v$, a face $f$, and an edge $e$ of $f$ containing $v$, and map it to the same face $f$, any vertex $w$ of $f$, and either of the edges $e'$ of $f$ containing $w$.

Comment: i think this may not be true in general - note that question as i posed it requires that every face is vertex transitive in such a way that the face is mapped to its self. Some isogonal figures appear to violate this, for example the distorted hexagon prism lacks the symmetry for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_figure

Comment: @jdizzle: those aren't regular. If you mean vertex- and face-to-face transitive, but not regular, those are [Noble polyhedra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_polyhedron), and indeed you can't necessarily take one vertex to another on the same face while fixing the face.